# Google Trends: difference in results between general UI and /fetchComponent

Tags: google-api, google-trends

Google Trends has a general UI where they they give you the chart for a query. There is also a `/trends/fetchComponent` method to extract the data. While it is natural to assume they would produce the same result, the reality is different.

For example, here are two queries to get the trends for the word 'dog' in Medford-Klamath Falls metro-area in the US for the last 6 years:

1. using the [general UI](https://www.google.com/trends/explore?date=2011-01-01%202017-01-01&geo=US-OR-813&q=dog);
2. using the [/trends/fetchComponent](https://www.google.com/trends/fetchComponent?q=dog&cid=TIMESERIES_GRAPH_0&export=3&geo=US-OR-813&date=today%2072-m) method.

It's easy to see that the results are different. So what is the difference between these two methods?

Comment: That `fetchComponent` thing is unofficial and undocumented - so who knows? And which results are different - they all look the same to me?? Perhaps it doesn't respect locations in the same way via the 'API' and web - but again, as nothing is documented who knows?

Comment: For example, the results for November and December 2016 are (95, 91) for the UI and (80,100) for the fetchComponent thing.